# Software or extension to view images on Google full screen with navigation

Tags: chrome, google-search

When I search a name on Google image search, it shows a lot of images. When clicking on them, Google opens a small image on the right side, which one can navigate with arrow keys.
Is it possible to navigate the full-screen pics in some way?